# c# WPF How to Remove listview header seperator line?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[image]

How to Remove this header seperator line

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    ...
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

this is my ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, is this not just a matter of setting the `BorderThickness` property to zero on your `ListView`?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" BorderThickness="0">
```

That should be the solution given the information provided in your question.

If you define some container in your `ItemTemplate` that has a border, the solution would be similar.