# WPF double line on the top of listbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I am new to wpf. I need to have a window that list all accounts added. But my application shows a double line below the "Accounts". Not sure what caused this. could someHow to fix this? Here is my xaml

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="444">
            <TextBlock x:Name="AddAccountTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="369" Text="Add account to allow for simple access to your company resources&#xD;&#xA;" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
            <Button x:Name="AddAccount" Content="Add Account" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" RenderTransformOrigin="0.466,0.977" IsCancel="True" Height="40" Foreground="White" Background="Blue" Click="OnAddAccount"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel2" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="154" Width="444">
            <TextBlock x:Name="AccountsTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Accounts" Height="25" Width="68" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Tahoma"/>
            <ListBox x:Name="accounts" Height="130" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                    <Border Name="_Border" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0.5" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                        <ContentPresenter />
                                    </Border>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                            <Setter TargetName="_Border" Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Source="{Binding Path=imagePath}" />
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=userInfo}"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: I think you will the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49835900/7159784). Just set `BorderThickness` to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You may remove the borders of the `ListBox` by setting the `BorderThickness` property:

```
<ListBox x:Name="accounts" Height="130" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="100"
    BorderThickness="0">
```

You may set it to `1,0,1,0` to remove only the top and bottom borders. The order is left, top, right, bottom.